# multi-user cluster: IBM Platform LSF: user changing priority of jobs

Tags: cluster-computing, priority-queue, hpc, lsf

I am user of a multi-user cluster that uses IBM Platform LSF (on Linux). I would like to change the priority of my jobs with respect to my same jobs (not the absolute priority of the jobs in the queue).

An example: I have launched 500 jobs in the queues that will take 4 days to complete, and later I would like submit another job that I would like to run before the 500 jobs that I have already submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of ways I can think of here:

1. Use user assigned priority on your job (`-sp` option) when you submit it with `bsub`, a higher number means more important.  Some notes:

   - This only works if your administrator has defined `MAX_USER_PRIORITY` in configuration (I can't for the life of me remember if this is set out of the box). To check if it's enabled run `bparams -a | grep MAX_USER_PRIORITY`, if it returns something you're good to go.
   - By default jobs have a priority of `$MAX_USER_PRIORITY / 2`, so if `MAX_USER_PRIORITY = 100` and you've submitted 500 jobs without `-sp` and you want to submit one job that jumps the queue, use `bsub -sp` with a priority greater than 50.
2. Another way to do it is by using `btop` which usually works out of the box.  Basically you submit your job normally, then use `btop <jobid>` to move a particular job to the front of the line relative to your other jobs.

Some links for you:

- `bsub -sp` documentation: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_command_ref/bsub.sp.1.html
- `btop` documentation: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_command_ref/btop.1.html
- blog post on user-assigned priority: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1013109